# How to model data i Graph databases

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, graph-databases

How should I think when having the graph data model below and for example reading the `Servers` that a `Databases Server` runs on is a common query?

I guess I could get that by first reading all the `App` for that `Server` and then the `VM` for that `App` and finally the `Server` for that `VM`. Or should I add other edge, besides the existing `App` uses edge, that tells me directly what `Server` that the `Database Server` runs on?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should add another edge from Database to Server. Something like the following where your Databases are deployed on Servers where VMs for Apps are running... assuming your databases are not running in VMs!

Sample property graph model:
[image]

Comment: Great, thanks, so I should always aim for adding a edge that will give me a shorter path in common queries? As long as the edge makes sense of course? Even if that adds an extra edge that would necessarily have to be there otherwise I guess ...